# In WPF, when selecting a TreeViewItem, how do I Focus on another control but still complete my TreeViewItem selection?

Tags: wpf, treeview

This sounds like a tricky question... let me ellaborate...

I have a treeView. When a treeViewItem is clicked/selected, I would like another TextBox to be focused.

The problem is that as soon as I add code to Focus the Textbox, it looks like the TreeView does not Show its selected node anymore (i.e. the treeItem is not Selected at all (or at least not visibly)).

Here is my event handling code...

```
    private void trvTree_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        grpEditTreeItem.DataContext = (TreeItemDefinition)e.NewValue;


        txtToken.SelectAll();
        txtToken.Focus();
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide more details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distinguish between Selected and Focused. You cannot have more than 1 Control focused at any one time.

What you want is your TreeView to **Show** it's selectednode when it has lost the focus.

Edit:
But I can confirm the problem, setting the Focus to another Control inside SelectedItemChanged() will Cancel the selection.

So what you need is something to postpone the Focus() call. A rough (but not ideal) solution is to place  txtToken.Focus() in a trvTree_MouseUp() event handler. But that will also take the Focus away when expanding a Node for example.

So you will probably have to use a one-shot timer fired from SelectedItemChanged() .

Comment: You can also queue the focus call on the dispatcher. I almost use this as the default these days as that way it does not interfere with the current execution frame, and it seems 90% of the time it does what you want in a given situation

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
{
    txtToken.SelectAll();
    txtToken.Focus();
});
```